# WFFM sitecore module installation - bin\System.Data.SQLite.x32 access denied

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to install the WFFM module for sitecore, After the installation is complete and the placeholder settings are provided i get the following error

> Access to the path
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXX\Website\bin\System.Data.SQLite.x32' is
>   denied

[image]

So the WFFM database is not created under web root /data folder (I guess)

I'm having hard time understanding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a permissions issue, make sure your `IUSR` or `NETWORK SERVICE` has `modify` permissions set on your \bin directory. Part of the post-install step of the WFFM module is to copy across the correct version of the SQLite dll, based on whether you are using x86 or x64 architecture.

You can rectify this manually by renaming `System.Data.SQLite.x32` to `System.Data.SQLite.dll` in the bin directory. If you on a x64 system then copy across the dll from the `bin_x64` instead.

I would suggest rather than using SQLite that you:

- Attach or restore the backup of the WebForms databases located in `/data` to SQL Server (personally I move these to the same location as the other Sitecore databases)
- Add a connection string named `wfm` in connectionStrings.config with the correct connection details
- or, modify the `<formsDataProvider>` in forms.config

If you need to run the Restricting Placeholders wizard again then click
*Sitecore > All Applications > Web Forms for Marketers > Restricting Placeholders.*

See section 3.4.2 of the [WFFM reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/23/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20reference-a4.pdf).